# Dynamically create a css selector for Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, css-selectors

I have some pixel differences between Chrome and Safari, I haven't been able to find a suitable way to deliver different styles to each of them using a css hack.

I have been able to fix it with javascript but there is a delay as the page loads and before it is applied, so the user sees movement.

```
function chromeStyle() {
if (window.chrome) {
var a = document.getElementById("id");
if (a) {
a.style.marginLeft = 5px;
}
}
}
```

I know that it is possible to place the following code into the head of an html document and then use ".JS .mystyle{}" in a stylesheet to apply styles where javascript is enabled.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.documentElement.className = 'JS';
</script>
```

I wondered if in a similar manner it would be possible to create a selector for Chrome that could be applied in a stylesheet?

```
if (window.chrome) {
create a selector for chrome here
}
```

and in the stylesheet apply it as ".chrome .mystyle{}".

Thanks.

Comment: The web will never be pixel-accurate. Deal with it.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to user browser-specific classes and unfortunately quite common. I'd recommend to ask first about your actual CSS problem though, before trying to fix it with JS.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is easier then what you're trying to do with JS.
But when i need to override certain styles for a specific browser I just create a check for the browser serverside, and then include an extra stylesheet that overrides the base styles.